# PHP fatal error - out of memory - tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes

Tags: php, sql, memory-management

I have a PHP function that is getting data from an SQL DB. Sometimes I get this fatal error while doing odbc_result

- Step 30 from 60 | Memory 191908
- Step 31 from 60 | Memory 191908
- Step 32 from 60 | Memory 191908
- Step 33 from 60 | Memory 191908
- Step 34 from 60 | Memory 191892
- Step 35 from 60 | Memory 191908
- Step 36 from 60 | Memory 191908
- Step 37 from 60 | Memory 191892
- Step 38 from 60 | Memory 191908
- Step 39 from 60 | Memory 191908
- PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 262144) (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes)

This is a piece of my output from the function.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

```
          while(odbc_fetch_row($exec_query_tblKlantFactuurOpdrachten))
    {
        $dataADDRow_1 = $doc->createElement("tblKlantFactuurOpdrachten");
        $dataADDRow->appendChild($dataADDRow_1);

        $i_1 = 1;
        while($i_1 < $numFields_1)
        {
            echo "Step ".$i_1." from ".$numFields_1." | Memory ".memory_get_usage()."\n";
            $dataFromDB = odbc_result($exec_query_tblKlantFactuurOpdrachten,$i_1);
            $dataADD = $doc->createElement($tmpArr_FieldName_1[$i_1],protectInfo($dataFromDB));
            $dataADDRow_1->appendChild($dataADD);
            flush();
            ++$i_1;
        }
        flush();

    }
```

I've retried to get the data from the DB with a simple query and when i try to get the same exact field I get that error also. So it seems that is something with the relationship between DB and PHP. I am using freetds driver on linux server.

When I get the data with SQL Server Management there is no problem.

Comment: `tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes` --- O_o

Comment: That looks like a loop in your code. Allocating 4GB of memory shouldn't be necessary for your application, i guess. What's in that database, and how is that query looking?

Comment: the data is too big and.....your server is running out of memory. increase it or optimize your query. I suggest the latter.

Comment: Server has a lot of free memory ... other posts did not help me in this case. Error is on ODBC_RESULT

Comment: Why is this closed? My problem is still there after trying all of the things that are mentioned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug in the ODBC-handling of PHP.

Something similar like this:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51606

Try the patch given there

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to an unending loop or some function called recursively that keeps allocating data.

You could try with:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

but if I'm right you'll get that error again. If so, then look for loops and recursive calls.